# Linux shell script not setting variables with bash -c "$com"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aircrack-ng

So, I wrote a shell script to kick people off of my wifi, but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly. The main problem is that when I do bash -c "$com" it does not set the variable like it should. Any help would be appreciated.

```
echo "You must be connected to the network that you wish to kick the devices off"
gw=`route -n|grep ^0.0.0.0|cut -d' ' -f 10`
sudo nmap -sP $gw-254
long='read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid'
a=1
end=';'
oend='&'
outside='"'
thesudo='sudo'
num=1
deff='aireplay-ng -0 $number -a $bssid mon0 --ignore-negative-one -c'
read -p "How many devices do you want to kick: " ammount
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $ammount ];
do
    b=device
    d1=$b$a

    if [ $counter2 -gt $ammount ]
    then
        com="$com $long $outside$d1$outside" 
        counter=$(($counter +1))
    else
        com="$com $long $outside$d1$outside $end"
    fi


    comfin="$comfin $thesudo $deff $d1 $oend"
    a=$(($a +1))
    counter=$(($counter +1))
    counter2=$(($counter +2))
done
vev="echo done"
comfin="$comfin $vev"
echo $com
bash -c "$com"
#Why does it not set the variables like it should?
echo $device1
echo $device2
echo $device3
#see it dosent say the variables when it is run.
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo macchanger -m 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
sudo ifconfig mon0 down
sudo macchanger -m 00:11:22:33:44:55 mon0
sudo ifconfig mon0 up

#make sure you dont run it from the file, but from terminal so you can press ctrl z to stop the airodump
echo "make sure you dont run it from the file, but from terminal so you can press ctrl z to stop the airodump"
sleep 2
sudo airodump-ng mon0

read -p "Enter the NETWORK Bssid:" bssid
echo "Ok, its $bssid"

read -p "Do you want to single kick(1) or continuously kick(0)" number
echo "Ok, its $number"

sudo $comfin

sudo ipconfig stop mon0
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Also worth running this whole thing through http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Also, for a more literal answer on how best to set variables named by a variable, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 (hint: no, the answer *doesn't* involve `eval`).

Answer (score 1):

`bash -c "command"` runs the command in a new `bash` process. Variable settings in that process won't have any effect on the original process. If you want to execute a command in the original process's environment, use `eval`:

```
eval "$com"
```

You probably should reconsider your whole approach, though. Dynamically assigning variables is usually a sign of an incorrect design. Instead of having separate variables `device1`, `device2`, `device3`, you should use an array.

```
read -p 'Enter the device' dev
device[$counter]=$dev
```

Comment: True if one _must_ run an arbitrary string through the parser, but that's not exactly best-practices if at all avoidable; far safer to collect the arguments in an array and run that exactly.

Comment: `device+=( "$dev" )` has been around long enough for it to be safe that any given version of bash has it available, no?

Comment: Yeah. I don't do enough shell scripting of this sort for that to stick in my mind.